# What is the best query for php-mysql search?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search engine which is pretty straight forward. The query is below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' 
        OR place LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' 
        OR country LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        OR date LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        LIMIT 40";
```

But, Problem with this is this, 
if I put the 'eventname' in search-box it is okay and it saws data from eventname column correctly. Or if I search only for place or country or date individually, it shows data correctly. But, if I search (FOR EXAMPLE) for both eventname and place together search results shows nothing. Using this query what are the changes I have to make to get it working?

Additionally I want to say that I have seen some of the query like "MATCH ... AGAINST". Though I don't want to use that, but if there are no other way what could be that "MATCH...AGAINST" query for this?

Here is my full code. They are straight forward. And I am working on a weird client's project and he want it to be like this and security is not a fact for him. So, you might notice some security issue which will be solved later. but the query first.

```
<?php  

include_once("admin/connection/db.php");
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' 
        OR place LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' 
        OR country LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        OR date LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        OR date AND country LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        OR date AND place LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        OR date AND eventname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
        LIMIT 40";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= "<a class='search-result' href='".$row["link_pdf"]."'><li><i class='fa fa-trophy'> </i> ".$row["eventname"].'<br/>'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row["date"])).' ||  '.$row["place"].', '.$row["country"].'<img src="logos/'.$row["country"].'.png" width="30px" height="18px;" /></li></a>';
    }
    echo $output;
}else {
    echo "<li>No Data Found Macthing Your Query</li>";
}

?>
```

Here is the link where you can check it directly
[http://speed-timing2.6te.net/](http://speed-timing2.6te.net/#)

Comment: u can try like (condition one OR condition two OR condition three) all condition inside the `()`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: Please use the way like this : ` where name like '%' + replace(search_criteria, '%', '[%]') + '%'`

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your query from a syntax point of view (performance is a different story). You have to show us sample data and sample search expression. Also, you need to make sure that your query does not produce any sql error messages (you have not shared with us how you call the sql statement - so it may be that you have unhandled sql errors). Also note that your code is vulnerable to sql injection attack.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will be do that. That is just basic code get my solution in here

Comment: have you tried using die()...while executing you query does it print some errors??

Comment: That's good. Anyway, if you want to use `LIKE` in the way you do, you need to split the words in your search string and the do a `WHERE (eventname LIKE '%word1%' OR place LIKE '%word1%' OR..) OR (eventname LIKE '%word2%'...)`...and so on for each word. All though, performance wise, it might not be the best way (or it is, I actually don't know).

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your help. I have added the whole code in there which might help you to understand.

Thanks to every single one who looked on it and helping me

Comment: 1) You just assume that your query is successful, you do not do any error handling. You must check if the query is successful and print out the sql error message if it was not. 2) Your query has interesting sections, such as `OR date AND country LIKE`. date field will be converted to Boolean and the `and` requires the search criteria to be present in the table. If it is not, no result will be returned. Same applies to the other 2 instance where this code pattern is repeated.

Comment: [link](http://speed-timing2.6te.net/)  @Shadow You can check that live

Comment: You should break your search string by explode and make dynamic query.

Comment: I can't, your site is blocked by my workplace

Comment: The query is okay. If this wouldn't be then when I search only for date or only for place or any other (individually) they wouldn't show the results depends on that. but, I tried that and as you said, checked my query and it is really working @Shadow

Comment: Well, your query is not ok, but if you are not open to suggestions, then there is little point for me to continue with this topic.

Comment: I tried this query below to check the query
`if($result == false)
{ 
    echo "Didn't Update"; 
}`
and it didn't show me anything @Shadow So I thought it to be okay. Am I doing the correct checking actually which you meant ?

Answer (score -2):

I believe your search query term is for example "event_name place_name" and in this case your query will not work. You can use FULLTEXT search instead.

For example

```
at first set fulltext index for eventname, place, country field as those are string fields. 


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT *, MATCH (eventname, place, country) AGAINST ('".$_POST["search"]."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
                    FROM events 
                        ORDER BY score DESC
            ) AS temp 
            WHERE temp.score>0 OR temp.date LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'    
";
```

Please check manual here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: 1) The query does work, just produces different results from the expected. 2) Fulltext searches are likely to produce a different result than like '%whatever%'. To make your answer useful, you should explain the differences. 3) You would not search on the fields independently from each other, this is highly inefficient.

Comment: I am going to trying this, Thanks

Comment: You got it all wrong. 1) Fulltext search even in Boolean mode cannot include a starting wildcard. 2) Stopwords and minimum word length restrictions all apply. 3) Your code is inefficient since you search the fields separately.

Comment: There are only one input and where search term includes both event_name and place_name. Either we have to separate term by space and need to check with all words or we have to do fulltext search. Here the reference I sent it is wrong. The correct reference is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html though the sql is same.

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain Your code throws error. I never worked with Match...AGAINST Before, so can you write that correctly? that way I can experiment with it. 
php says 
"Expecting T_String ....."

Comment: @Allen sorry, I can't test in my working environment right now. I can do it later after office time. For now you can follow http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html and correct error accordingly.

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain Thanks a lot. Your help is really appreciated

Comment: @AllenTitan the error message you get is in php, not in MySQL. The code above does not follow php syntax for including parameters. Pls do not just copy and paste, we do make syntax errors as well.

Comment: @AllenTitan sql has been updated. if you can test and update test result that will be great. If you are not sure how to set full text index let me know.

The reason behind using of fulltext search is when you are creating a search engine and user can search by sentence contains separated words then splitting it and match using LIKE contains lot of condition and time matters too. For example I want to search by "USA California PHP conference".